# FieldError at /store/submit_review/1/ Unsupported lookup 'id' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
def submit_review(request, product_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            reviews = ReviewRating.objects.get( user__id = request.user.id, product__id=product_id)
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you ! your review has been updated.')
            return redirect(url)
        except ReviewRating.DoesNotExist:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = ReviewRating()
                data.subject = form.changed_data['subject']
                data.rating = form.changed_data['rating']
                data.review = form.changed_data['review']
                data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') #REMOTE_ADDR will stor the ip address
                data.product_id = product_id
                data.user_id = request.user.id
                data.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submitted.')
                return redirect(url)
```

error I got:

```
FieldError at /store/submit_review/1/
Unsupported lookup 'id' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/submit_review/1/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Unsupported lookup 'id' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Comment: What is code for models.py of `ReviewRating`  ? add whole models.py to your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.